# ArgumentError in Users#index for Hartl Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I keep running into an error when i try to see the index of users. This is in chapter 9 of Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial (an excellent tutorial)

wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

```
<li>
  <%= gravatar_for user, size: 52 %>
  <%= link_to user.name, user %>
  <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
    | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                  data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

I don't know why it thinks that line 2 thinks that I am calling 2 arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must have missed to follow the exercises in Chapter 7 (section 7.6) :).  If you look at that section, you'll see the updated helper in `app/helpers/users_helper.rb` as follows:

```
module UsersHelper

  # Returns the Gravatar (http://gravatar.com/) for the given user.
  def gravatar_for(user, options = { size: 50 })
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
    size = options[:size]
    gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}?s=#{size}"
    image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
  end
end
```

Once you update the helper, you should be able to use this method with two parameters.  The second parameter is optional, so if you call `gravatar_for user` (i.e. without the size parameter) then then the default size `50` is used, and if you call `gravatar_for user, size:52` then `52` will be used for the gravatar's size.

Comment: AH, i have been assuming that the exercises are optional

Comment: It worked. Thanks vino. If only i had the reputation to upvote you

Comment: @IanSteffy, Glad to be of help.  No worries about upvote, but if you feel this best answers your question, you could mark it as answer so that the question does not remain open.

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations on getting to Chap. 9! I'm bored to tears in Chap. 6

Line 2 is this:

```
<%= gravatar_for user, size: 52 %>
```

...which is equivalent to:

```
<%= gravator_for(user, {size: 52}) %>
```

That's two arguments.